# Swift 3 , CollectionView, Alamofire 4 : finding nil while unwrapping a value

Tags: uicollectionview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell, alamofire, swifty-json

Here is my **JSON** response

```
{
"category_list" : [
{
  "category_imag" : "http:\/\/xxx\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/10\/img-thing.jpg",
  "category_name" : "category 1",
  "category_description" : "dsadsadas",
  "category_id" : 6
},
{
  "category_imag" : "http:\/\/xxx\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/09\/7075hp_2_2.jpg",
  "category_name" : "category 2",
  "category_description" : "dasdadasdas",
  "category_id" : 12
  }
 ]
}
items are***********************************************
{
  "category_imag" : "http:\/\/xxx\/wp-   content\/uploads\/2016\/10\/img-thing.jpg",
 "category_description" : "dsadsadas",
 "category_name" : "category 1",
 "category_id" : 6
}
{
 "category_imag" : "http:\/\/xxx\/wp-  content\/uploads\/2016\/09\/7075hp_2_2.jpg",
 "category_description" : "dasdadasdas",
"category_name" : "category 2",
"category_id" : 12
  }
 items number***********************************************
2
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

here is the function I am using to fetch **JSON** using **Alamofire** & **SwiftyJSON**

```
func getJSON(){

    let getEndPoint: String = "http://xxx/api/category_list/"
    Alamofire.request(getEndPoint)
        .responseJSON { response in

            guard response.result.error == nil else {
                // got an error in getting the data, need to handle it
                print("error calling GET")
                print(response.result.error!)
                return
            }

            if let value = response.result.value {

                let json = JSON(value)
                print(json)
                // print(json["main_content"].array)
                let categoryList = json["category_list"].arrayValue
                for items in categoryList {

                    //self.productList += [HomeFeedJSON(items:items )]
                    self.getCategoryList.append(CategoryList(items: items))
                    print(items)

                }

                print("items are***********************************************")
                print(self.getCategoryList.count)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.afData = 1
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                }

            }
    }

}
```

and here is the model **class** I am using for assigning the values fetched from **JSON**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

class CategoryList {

var category_name: String?
var category_imag: URL?
var category_description: String?


init(items: JSON){
    self.category_name = items["category_name"].stringValue
    self.category_imag = items["category_imag"].URL
    self.category_description =    items["category_description"].stringValue

  }

}
```

I don't want to bother people but I have tried all possible way I could, its showing **nil** on my **collectionViewCell** . in **numberOfItemsInSection** I am getting intended result but at **cellForItemAt indexPath** it shows **nil** value and crashes. Here is my **cellForItemAt indexPath**

```
  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CatagoryShopCell", for: indexPath) as! CatagoryShopCell

    if afData == 1 {

      let myCategory = self.getCategoryList[indexPath.row]

      cell.catagoryName.text = myCategory.category_name
      cell.catagoryDesc.text = myCategory.category_description

    let categoryImg = myCategory.category_imag
    SDWebImageManager.shared().downloadImage(with: categoryImg, options: [], progress: nil) { downloadedImage, error, cacheType, isDownloaded, url in
            cell.catagoryPicture.image = downloadedImage
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

I have used the same function/model class in a **tableView** in it works just fine, but I can't sort it out how its not finding value in my model class here at **collectionView** . Please any kind person help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your debugger telling you. Which object or property is nil.

Comment: **cell.catagoryName.text = myCategory.category_name** its showing nail , that means other values are nil as well

Comment: Check `catagoryName` Outlet is properly connected with your `CollectionViewCell`.

Comment: Oo my god !! I have been searching for ages but couldn't find out where did I go wrong . Its exactly spot on , somehow two of my outlets were missing among three . Thank you so much again @NiravD , the savior :)